# What type of container should I use to store my ObjectID integer?

Tags: c++, list, vector, iteration, containers

I feel like this is a very simple, almost stupid question. I simply have forgotten what I should know how to do.

I have GameObjects, which are stored in a universal GameObjectManager. These GameObjects have an ObjectID, which is a simple int.

I need to be able to insert or remove these GameObjects in a 2D tile based world, where each TILE holds a container of ObjectID's.

This way, I can grab a specific tile (ex. Tile[10][10]) and then see what GameObjects are on Tile[10][10] by reading from the container. (ex. "Ah, so Character#4302 and Item#123 are on Tile[10][10]!")

Right now, each "Tile" is a structure in a MAP array of Tiles.

```
 struct MapTile
 {
     std::vector <int> GameObject_MapList ; //list of Objects on this map location
    TileTerrainType tileTerrainType; //GFX to display Grass, Sand, Water, Swamp, etc.
 };

 MapTile mlMap[100][100]; //map array
```

However, I read that Vectors should not be used when arbitrarily adding/removing variables. It is not like I will be removing the first or last variable in the array. Instead, I will have to call a specific ObjectID and remove it from wherever it is in the array.

For this reason, I was thinking of using a different container.
Maybe I am just too tired, but I could use some advice on what container to use, and how to go about removing SPECIFIC variables in the container.

For example, GameObject has an ObjectID of "422".
Tile[2][8] holds a container that has the following integers in order: 420, 421, 422, 433, 486, 800.

I have a function: RemoveGameObjectFromMap(int ObjectID);
So I need it to remove 422, whenever I type (RemoveGameObjectFromMap(422);

I used to use a MAP container, but that is unnecessary. Vector, according to cplusplus.com would be bad for this.

Comment: Perhaps I am confused because I am not handling my classes correctly. The more I think about this, the more I realize I should probably allow the MAP class full access to the WORLD class's GameObjectManager. I am only doing this because my former way of handling this (a MAP which held the actual gameobjects) is because the TILES no longer hold the actual GameObjects, and instead just hold their int ObjectID.

Comment: Whether vector is good or bad depends on a number of things. Like how many IDs per tile (on average), how frequent insertions, deletions and lookups are, how much need there is to minimise memory use, and a 100 other considerations. In short there are no simple answers. The obvious alternative to std::vector in this case though would be std::unordered_set (I'm assuming that you never want the same ID in the same tile more than once).

Comment: The insertions and deletions are constant. Anytime the player moves a little bit, they will be deleted and inserted to a new MapTile.

Comment: Yes! std::unordered_set is exactly what I was needing. Please make this your answer, not your comment, so I can close it and give you the points.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting an odd error. "unordered_set in namespace std does not name a type"

Comment: Have you said `#include <unordered_set>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether a vector is good or bad depends on a number of things. Like how many IDs per tile (on average), how frequent insertions, deletions and lookups are, how much need there is to minimise memory use, and a 100 other considerations. In short there are no simple answers. The obvious alternative to `std::vector` in this case though would be `std::unordered_set` (I'm assuming that you never want the same ID in the same tile more than once).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to store about 10-20 elements - use vector. Especially for POD elements. I'm not sure about `std::unordered_set` but map will give you a lot of memory allocations which will devour any speed boost from fast insert and erase. To speed up search you can sort vector and use some binary search ([lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) [equal_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_bound)).

Comment: What does additional memory allocation (wasted memory) have to do with speed boast when performing insert/erase functions?

Memory Consumption and Processing Speed aren't related like that, are they?

I thought this is what Maps were made for. You're saying that sorting a vector and using binary search is superior to a Map, despite the Map being made FOR this very reason?

From the Cplusplus website: "Maps are typically implemented as binary search trees." 

Maybe I am too newbie to understand what you are saying? If a Map is so awful in its strengths, why does it exist?

Comment: @Carter81: Cache is the answer. All I said is right for 10-20 elements case. Map and list are superior at big sizes, but the items may be scattered throughout the memory. At small ones the price for coping is small and the benefits from cache hits are great. So if your container is going to be small - use vector.